# How did fetch records inserted on exactly on 15th day before from current date in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

please help, i want to list of records that can be **inserted exactly on 15th day  from current date**  in MySQL **(no record from less than 14 days before and no records greater than 15 days  )** .Suppose today's date is 05/03/2018 so exact 15 days before from now date was 18/02/2018,so i need the whole list of record that has been inserted on 18/02/2018. i search for the solutions but i did not get any solution....thanks in advance

Comment: it's not perfectly clear. You mean it must be the 15th of any month ?

Comment: not 15th of any months its past entries inserted exact on 15th day from current date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after couple of hours i got my solution...thanks for your support..its works perfectly for me ...

SELECT *
FROM table_name 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(created_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 15 DAY);
+-----------------------------------------+
| DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 15 DAY) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2018-02-15                              |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATE(dateColumn)=CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 15 DAY;
```

See [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/929cfe/2).

See [MySQL DATE() function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date.asp).